# Entity framework standalone project vs entity set within main project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

There seems to be something strange happening with regards to adding an entity set to an existing project vs having an entity set in its own project for re-usability.

**Scenario One**
Project A is a class library and has an EF set added to it and connected to a database.
Within the default class in the class library project, this code is written and compiles fine.

```
  public void test()
    {
        using (var context = new Accu_CRM_dbEntities())
        {
            var test = context.BillableParts.First(P => P.Id == "test");
        }
    }
```

**Scenario Two**
Project B is another project added to the same solution. A reference is made to project A so as to use the identities in project B. A using statement is placed in the code file that is going to be making dB calls with the EF set. The same code is written into project B; however, the compiler complains that `'DAL.Accu_CRM_dbEntities': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'`. Aside from this, all intellisense support is lost when dealing with the context.

If I type `context.BillableParts.` intellisense support ceases after the entity name. What exactly is the reason that project B cannot see that `Accu_CM_dbEntities` should be disposable the way it is in project A?

```
namespace DAL
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class Accu_CRM_dbEntities : DbContext
{
    public Accu_CRM_dbEntities()
        : base("name=Accu_CRM_dbEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<BillablePart> BillableParts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BillableService> BillableServices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Part> Parts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PartsManufacturer> PartsManufacturers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<WorkOrder> WorkOrders { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Sounds like whatever is returned by `BillableParts` is internal, or has mostly internal definitions.

Comment: can you post your "Accu_CM_dbEntities" class?

Comment: @JuanP what exactly do you mean, by "plugging it in?"

Comment: @Larry I updated my question with the `Accu_CM_dbEntities` class

Comment: do you reference EntityFramework from project B ?

Comment: @tschmit007 I did; however, I did not reference the sql server compact version. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some more information on the database would have been a bit more useful. I am using SQL server compact. I used nuget and installed EF for sql compact within my consuming project (consumer of EF project) and everything was fixed. I am not 100% sure what was the issue exactly but obviously I did not have the correct libraries referenced. I'll leave this up here for anyone else that might be getting this error